# Where are Automatic Type Acquisition typescript definition files saved?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I'm in environment with blocked access to github, typing and I want to have enhanced intellisense in vscode.

To do so I suppose I need to copy cached typescript definitions from machine that does have it for various needed npm packages.

So question where I can find those cached ata ts files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please consider an alternative, but here are the standard locations:

- Mac: `~/Library/Caches/TypeScript`
- Windows: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\TypeScript`
- Linux: `~/.cache/typescript/`

As a better solution, if you cannot rely on automatic typings acquisition, you can manually manage type typings files. [Here's some documentation information](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/). For example:

```
$ npm install --save @types/express
```

This will download a copy of the express typings files to the normal `node_modules` folder your project. If you can't use npm, this is a much better place to copy files between.

Typings files are required to builds TypeScript projects, but are only used to enhance VSCode IntelliSense with JavaScript projects.

Hope that clears things up.

Comment: In %LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\TypeScript where should i put npm package @types/node to have node intellisense installed globally?

Comment: @UnderNotic I strongly recommend against altering those files since they are managed by TypeScript. Please install types locally instead if you need this. However, that shared typescript folder is just an npm package so you can just use the normal npm commands on it, or copy folders into its `node_modules` folder. This is unsupported and there is no certainty it will work

Comment: Okay, i tried with shared typescript folder and this doesn't work, but anyway types installed locally per project work just fine