# When I import a type from an NPM package in Typescript, which file is it coming from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

E.g. when I do:

```
import type React from 'react';

function Foo({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren<{}>);
```

Where does `React.PropsWithChildren` come from? It's not in React's Github repo and it's not in `node_modules/react`. I have a limited understanding of how DefinitelyTyped works, but there isn't a `node_modules/@types/react` folder and I never installed `@types/react`.

How is Typescript able to resolve this?

Comment: Can your IDE tell you? Cmd-B takes me to the definition in `./node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts`, and without the React types folder a *lot* of things break.

Comment: VS code also still has automatic type acquisition, right? See if the types are in one of those folders: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40941936/1497533  then likely vs code automatically downloaded the types

Answer (score 2):

Javascript resolving system recursively look for `node_modules` folders, it means it first look at the directory that your code is in, if not found, then the upper directory and so on.

<strike>In your case, chances are you have installed the `@types/react` somewhere in upper directories or even globally.</strike>

As @AluanHaddad correctly mentioned, apparently Typescript doesn't fallback to globally installed type packages. in VSCode BTW there's a caching mechanism (`Automatic Type Acquisition`), whenever it can't find the types in your directory `node_modules`, it then look for the types in below directories:

- Mac: ~/Library/Caches/TypeScript
- Windows: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\TypeScript
- Linux: ~/.cache/typescript/

if not found, it then proceed to download the missing types from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) and put them in aforementioned directories.

Comment: You're right about the upper directories, but typescript doesn't fallback to globally installed @types packages

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'm not exactly sure about the way typescript types work honestly, but I'm sure that either typescript server or the VSCode look for types somewhere in my C drive when I haven't installed the types locally. maybe it's some kind of cache mechanism.

Comment: Yes, it's a cache for automatically acquired types. It doesn't look at Global packages though

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know how TypeScript resolve `PropsWithChildren`. But you said you didn't install `@types/react`. I think in this situation the TypeScript compiler can't resolve this.

If you want to use TypeScript with React first install `@types/react`

Foo.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';

function Foo({ children }: React.PropsWithChildren<{}>);
```

Comment: Hey jonrsharpe I want to ask somethin. In stack overflow it is bad to use some template? I'm not angry about editing just want to know about stack overflow ! Cuz all of my answer is likes previous my answer @jonrsharpe

Comment: Not necessarily, but having a TL;DR for an answer that's only six lines long, with all of the extra formatting making the answer twice the vertical size, is counterproductive.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks for your advice:)

Comment: I don't understand how this got 3 downvotes. You definitely want to install `@types/react` and explicitly. Doing so is easy `myFavoritePackageManger install @types/react`